# Merge object together

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects that I want merge together

```
Object1 = {'1234':{name: 'One'},'4567': {name: 'two'}}
Object2 = {'1234':{id: 1234, location: 'paris'},'4567':{id: 4567, location: 'london'}}
```

If the id match the object key , merge it it.

I want a result like this:

```
Object3 = {'1234':{id: 1234, name: 'One', location: 'paris'},'4567':{id: 4567, name: 'two', location: 'london'}}
```

If I try spread operator or Object.assign , it overwrite the previous object.

Comment: You should include your code and explain how it's failing.

Comment: `Object2` is not valid. It has no keys. It looks like it should be an array.

Comment: Your second object isn't valid JavaScript, so the parser is going to fail long before you ever even try to test your logic.

Comment: I edited the second object

Comment: Do the two objects always have the same keys?

Comment: Loop through the properties of one object, merging it with the corresponding property of the other object using `Object.assign()` or spread.

Comment: How can I do that ? @Barmar

Comment: `Object3[key] = {...Object1[key], ...Object2[key]}`

Comment: Yes I know , I already try something like Object3 = {...Object1, ...Object2} but nothing work

Comment: you have to merge the nested objects, not the main objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You most likely want to iterate through one of the objects and merge each value.

```
const Object1 = {'1234':{name: 'One'},'4567': {name: 'two'}};
const Object2 = {'1234':{id: 1234, location: 'paris'},'4567':{id: 4567, location: 'london'}};
const Object3 = {};

for (let key in Object1) {
    Object3[key] = {...Object2[key], ...Object1[key]}
}

console.log(Object3);
```

Additionally you can add some if statements to check whether or not key exist in both objects.